# How to get the cities when pass the province in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in reactjs, and I want that when I pass a province it will return of it's cities. I try npm but I can't any. I appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: This question is not only too broad as it can be answered many many ways, it's also unclear what you're asking and of very low quality. Please take the tour or have a look at the help center! Thanks.

Comment: @Clijsters , what i mean is , I have a dropdown, where in the provinces can be chosen, then when I choose a province, I want that the cities will be shown of the province that I choose and will be put also in dropdown.

Comment: Which provinces? Where? What? From countries? If yes, which contry? Where does your province data set come from? Which kind of dropdown? `<select>`? and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something generic would be something like the example in the following link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zk3m3n4zzx

I'm basically using the state to store the address selected.

```
const data = {
  provinces: [
    { id: 1, name: 'P1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'P2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'P3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'P4' },
  ],
  cities: [
    { id: 1, name: 'C1', provinceId: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'C2', provinceId: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'C3', provinceId: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: 'C4', provinceId: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'C5', provinceId: 2 },
    { id: 6, name: 'C6', provinceId: 3 },
    { id: 7, name: 'C7', provinceId: 4 },
  ]
};

class Province extends React.Component {
  onSelect = (event) => {
    this.props.onSelect(parseInt(event.target.value));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Province: </span>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect} >
          <option>Select province</option>
          {
            this.props.data.map(prov => (
              <option
                key={prov.id}
                value={prov.id}
                selected={this.props.selectedId === prov.id}>
                {prov.name}
              </option>
            ))
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class City extends React.Component {
  onSelect = (event) => {
    this.props.onSelect(parseInt(event.target.value));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>City: </span>
        <select onClick={this.onSelect}>
          <option>Select city</option>
          {
            this.props.data.map(city => (
                <option
                  key={city.id}
                  value={city.id}
                  selected={this.props.selectedId === city.id}>
                  {city.name}
                </option>
            ))
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Address extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      provinces: data.provinces,
      provinceId: null,
      cities: data.cities,
      cityId: null
    };
  }

  onSelectProvince = (provId) => {
    const selCities = data.cities.filter(c => c.provinceId === provId);
    this.setState({
      provinceId: provId,
      cities: selCities
    });
  }

  onSelectCity = (city) => {
    this.setState({
      cityId: city.id
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Province
          data={this.state.provinces}
          selectedId={this.state.provinceId}
          onSelect={this.onSelectProvince} />
        <City
          data={this.state.cities}
          selectedId={this.state.cityId}
          onSelect={this.onSelectCity} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro ! I will try this

Comment: yeah, i just make another files of cities and province then call them. Thanks bro !